# Mean Preserving Discretisation of a Truncated Continuous Random Variable

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, self-learning

As suggested by the title, I am trying to determine how to generate a discretised version of a continuous random variable, that is truncated to the right by some value, say $M$.
I would like the resultant discretised random variable to have the same mean as the continuous version.

If I ignore truncation for the moment, I have found the following *result* that I am not able to verify:

If $Y$ is the discretised version of some continuous r.v. $X$, for *bandwidth* $h$, if we let

$f_{j} = P(Y = jh)$

Then:

$f_{0} = 1- \frac{E[X\hspace{0.1cm}\wedge\hspace{0.1cm}h]}{h}$

$f_{j} = \frac{2E[X\hspace{0.1cm}\wedge\hspace{0.1cm}jh] - E[X\hspace{0.1cm}\wedge\hspace{0.1cm}(j-1)h] - E[X\hspace{0.1cm}\wedge\hspace{0.1cm}(j+1)h]}{h}$

And $Y$ will have the same mean as $X$.

I am struggling to explain these formulae intuitively (although I can sort of *see* that we are finding the average of $X$ at increments along the doman, where the increments are determined by the value of $h$).

I am certainly struggling to derive a mathematical and rigorous proof.

Can anyone help on both parts?

Perhaps if I grasp this then I will be able to determine the formulae for the truncated version.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It would help to know the purpose/application you have in mind. In practice, this is done quite regularly using histograms (centerpoints of bins and bin heights), and perhaps more elegantly, by density estimators. The analogy seems strong enough that it might be worthwhile to read about kernel density estimation (KDE), perhaps beginning with Silverman's very clearly written book. The term 'bandwidth' is also used in KDE.

Comment: Thanks BruceET I appreciate the reply. I am familiar with KDE as a method to smooth a "noisy" distribution. My purpose is in fact to take an already smooth distribution and "turn" it into a PDF. Particularly so I can use Panjer-Recursion estimation upon it (rather than simulating). I could indeed use centrepoints of bins and heights, but this may not guarantee the means of my original curve and new PDF match. The above formulae is (apparently) a solution to my issue. But I can neither prove it nor get it to work in practice. Thanks for any help.

Comment: From your additional explanation, I'm getting the inkling that I have seen a solution to this in my dim distant past. Suggest you also post this on our [_statistics site_](https://stats.stackexchange.com) including the full explanation in your comment. [Of course, a key issue is deciding how far into the tail of a long-tailed distribution you need to go. I think you ought to be able to preserve the variance as well as the mean.]

Comment: Just to note that I have managed to use the formulae in practice for a variety of continuous distributions. Now I just need to understand the proof of it, and extend the use to truncated continuous random variables....

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you're looking for a completely general method. But many important
continuous distributions are approximated by discrete distributions
that are already programmed into major software packages. For example,
$\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=200,\sigma=10) \approx \mathsf{Binom}(n=400,1/2).$ For other normal distributions, you could re-scale the binomial. Using R:

[image]

For most purposes, the discrepancy between the discrete and continuous distributions is smaller than the margin of simulation error.

```
> x = rnorm(10^6, 200, 10);  mean(x);  sd(x)
[1] 200.0146
[1] 9.999379
> y = rbinom(10^6, 400, .5); mean(y);  sd(y)
[1] 199.9938
[1] 10.00215
```

Comment: Thanks Bruce - this is indeed a useful alternative where such approximations exist. You are correct that I am after a more general approach.

Comment: I guess geometric approximates exponential, (some version of) negative binomial approximates gammas with integer shape parameters, etc.

Comment: I guess geometric approximates exponential, (some version of) negative binomial approximates gammas with integer shape parameters, etc. // Seems the proof of your method is the same as for 'Riemann approximation': _Roughly,_ gridpoints $g_i$ spaced $\delta$ apart btw $a$ and $b$, and $h_i = f(g_i)$ imply $ \sum_i \delta h_j \approx P(a <X<b) = \int_a^b f(x)\,dx,$ approaching exact as $\delta   \rightarrow 0.$  Similarly for $E(X)$ and $g_if(g_i)$ if support of $X$ is in $(a,b)$ or adjustment is made for truncation. [Easiest if $f$ is bounded in $(a,b).$]